# Slicing from a list of column names and renaming them via assigning another list as names in those columns

Tags: python, pandas

So I've tried to slice a column names from my dataframe to rename them, but it doesn't seem to work.

What I've tried doing is the following:

```
rename_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

df.columns[9:14] = rename_list
```

This doesn't seem to work and returns the following error: `TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations`

However, renaming columns through a list without splicing the column names seems to work fine.

For instance if I wanted to rename `df2`, a new dataframe with only 5 columns, the following works:

```
rename_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

df2.columns = rename_list
```

The alternative of course is making a dictionary and using `df.rename()`, I'm just wondering if there's any way to get it done as suggested above, through simply slicing the needed column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create lists or 1d array and change by slicing, then assign back:

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
#pandas 0.24+
cols = df.columns.to_numpy()
#pandas below
#cols = df.columns.values
```

---

```
cols[9:15] = rename_list
df.columns = cols
```

Also working assign to underline 1d array, but in past version of pandas was weird errors, so not recommended:

```
df.columns.values[9:15] = rename_list
```